# Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name linkText

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that similar on site in "asp.net MVC for professional" book,
so i have a problem with navigation bar, problem in view.

the text of error is:
Value cannot be null or empty.
Имя параметра: linkText

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
  {
   @Html.RouteLink(link, new
  {
      controller = "Profile"

,
```

I understand that problem in link, but I have no idea how to fix it.

below code of controllers and view.
**Menu.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

    @Html.ActionLink("List", "Profile")
    @foreach (var link in Model)
    {
        @Html.RouteLink(link, new
    {
        controller = "Profile",
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    })
    }
```

**NavController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HoboAnimal.Domain.Abstract;


namespace HoboAnimal.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class NavController : Controller
    {
        private IProfileRepository repository;
        public NavController(IProfileRepository repo)
        {
            repository= repo;
        }
        public PartialViewResult Menu(){ 

            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Profiles.
                Select(x => x.Category).
                Distinct().
                OrderBy(x => x);
            return PartialView(categories);
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="categories">
        @{Html.Action("Menu","Nav");}
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is the markup for the `linkText` controller/element?

Comment: Added Layout.cshtml

Comment: Any specific line where you are getting the exception?

Comment: @Html.RouteLink(link, new

Comment: I guess it's problem with model in view, but i can't fix(

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the RouteLink, it seems it needs 3 parameters, you are only giving it 2. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).asp)

Comment: It should be `@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }` (or `@Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")`)

Comment: I tried. I guess i need to change RouteLink an add something

Comment: Are you sure there are no items in you collection that are empty strings?

Comment: My collection it's category's name from database. problem in view, not in controller, thank u

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in your view!

Comment: Sorry, u really  right , the main problem was with empty fields in database,Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since linkText is first argument of ActionLink and RouteLink, this mean that 1 or more of yours "link" in Model is empty string. Check it before create link:

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(link.toString())
  {
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
    {
        controller = "Profile",
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    })
  }
}
```

or remove empty rows from selection:

```
IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Profiles.
                Select(x => x.Category).
                Distinct().
                Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).
                OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> Value cannot be null or empty. Имя параметра: linkText

only says that the *linkText* parameter is needed (he can't be **null or empty**) in the *ActionLink* method.

for example you could write like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(" ","List", "Profile")
```

it should help.